# Maxim MAX14830 in Linux x86 / ACPI

Tags: linux-device-driver, acpi

I am receiving a fatal error when attempting to load the Maxim MAX14830 SPI-to-QuadUART chip in a CentOS8 (x86_64) environment. The SPI controller in use is the Intel E3900 Atom, from which I am able to successfully mount and interact with using SPIDEV.

After reviewing several examples from the ARM world, I believe the issue lies in that I am not passing the "clocks" parameter to the max310x driver, but I have been unable to find a suitable example for describing a "phandle to the IC source clock" in ACPI.

The chip's clock input (Pin 45, XIN) is driven by a standard clock oscillator running at 7.3728 MHz.

```asl
DefinitionBlock ("e3900-spi.aml", "SSDT", 5, "INTEL", "SPIDEV", 1)
{
    External (_SB_.PCI0.SPI1, DeviceObj)

    Scope (\_SB.PCI0.SPI1)
    {
        Device (MAX1) {
            Name (_HID, "PRP0001")
            Name (_DDN, "Maxim MAX14380 Quad UART")
            Name (_CRS, ResourceTemplate () {
                SpiSerialBus (
                    0,                      // Chip select
                    PolarityLow,            // Chip select is active low
                    FourWireMode,           // Full duplex
                    8,                      // Bits per word is 8 (byte)
                    ControllerInitiated,    // slave mode
                    1000000,                // 1 MHz
                    ClockPolarityLow,       // SPI mode 0
                    ClockPhaseFirst,        // SPI mode 0
                    "\\_SB.PCI0.SPI1",      // SPI host controller
                    0,                      // Must be 0
                    ResourceConsumer        // Slave device
                )
            })

            Name (_DSD, Package () {
                ToUUID("daffd814-6eba-4d8c-8a91-bc9bbf4aa301"),
                Package () {
                    Package () {"compatible", "maxim,max14830"},
                    Package () {"clock-names", "osc"},
                    Package () {"clock-frequency", 7372800},
                    Package () {"reg", 0},
                }
            })
        }

        Device (TP11) {
            Name (_HID, "SPT0001")
            Name (_DDN, "E3900-SPI1-CS1")
            Name (_CRS, ResourceTemplate () {
                SpiSerialBus (
                    1,                      // Chip select
                    PolarityLow,            // Chip select is active low
                    FourWireMode,           // Full duplex
                    8,                      // Bits per word is 8 (byte)
                    ControllerInitiated,    // Don't care
                    1000000,                // 1 MHz
                    ClockPolarityLow,       // SPI mode 0
                    ClockPhaseFirst,        // SPI mode 0
                    "\\_SB.PCI0.SPI1",      // SPI host controller
                    0                       // Must be 0
                )
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The relevant output from dmesg is:

```
[    1.974203] max310x spi-PRP0001:03: Cannot get clock
[    1.975951] max310x: probe of spi-PRP0001:03 failed with error -22
```

The datasheet for the part can be found here: https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX14830.pdf

Any guidance or relevant example link would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I found an example for how to reference another object at https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/firmware-guide/acpi/dsd/leds.html; the following AML complied correctly, but resulted in a kernel panic. This discussion (https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/914341e7-ca94-054d-6127-522b745006b4@arm.com/T/) leads me to believe that use of the common clock framework is not supported in ACPI, so any drivers that make use of it cannot be used with a ACPI + _DSD configuration.

```asl
DefinitionBlock ("e3900-spi.aml", "SSDT", 5, "INTEL", "SPIDEV", 1)
{
    External (_SB_.PCI0.SPI1, DeviceObj)

    Scope (\_SB.PCI0.SPI1)
    {

        Device (CLK1) {
            Name (_HID, "PRP0001")
            Name (_DDN, "Maxim Clock Object")
            Name (_DSD, Package () {
                ToUUID("daffd814-6eba-4d8c-8a91-bc9bbf4aa301"),
                Package () {
                    Package () {"compatible", "fixed-clock"},
                    Package () {"clock-cells", 0},
                    Package () {"clock-frequency", 7372800},
                }
            })
        }

        Device (MAX1) {
            Name (_HID, "PRP0001")
            Name (_DDN, "Maxim MAX14380 Quad UART")
            Name (_CRS, ResourceTemplate () {
                SpiSerialBus (
                    0,                      // Chip select
                    PolarityLow,            // Chip select is active low
                    FourWireMode,           // Full duplex
                    8,                      // Bits per word is 8 (byte)
                    ControllerInitiated,    // slave mode
                    100000,                 // 100 kHz
                    ClockPolarityLow,       // SPI mode 0
                    ClockPhaseFirst,        // SPI mode 0
                    "\\_SB.PCI0.SPI1",      // SPI host controller
                    0,                      // Must be 0
                    ResourceConsumer        // Slave device
                )
            })

            Name (_DSD, Package () {
                ToUUID("daffd814-6eba-4d8c-8a91-bc9bbf4aa301"),
                Package () {
                    Package () {"compatible", "maxim,max14830"},
                    Package () {"clock-names", "osc"},
                    Package () {"clocks", ^CLK1},
                    Package () {"reg", 0},
                }
            })
        }

        Device (TP11) {
            Name (_HID, "SPT0001")
            Name (_DDN, "E3900-SPI1-CS1")
            Name (_CRS, ResourceTemplate () {
                SpiSerialBus (
                    1,                      // Chip select
                    PolarityLow,            // Chip select is active low
                    FourWireMode,           // Full duplex
                    8,                      // Bits per word is 8 (byte)
                    ControllerInitiated,    // Don't care
                    1000000,                // 1 MHz
                    ClockPolarityLow,       // SPI mode 0
                    ClockPhaseFirst,        // SPI mode 0
                    "\\_SB.PCI0.SPI1",      // SPI host controller
                    0                       // Must be 0
                )
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no support for ACPI in CCF in Linux. Read this discussion about similar issue witn another device: https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-serial/msg32694.html. It may give you a hint what to do next.

Comment: Note to people who are voting negatively and/or recommending to close. You probably unfamiliar with ACPI, because the above is quite on topic: ASL is a programming language. Please, retract your opinions.

Comment: This series https://lore.kernel.org/linux-serial/20201007084635.594991-1-andy.shevchenko@gmail.com/ is a first step. Second one something like https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-serial/msg32696.html mentioned earlier.

Comment: Ah, and one more thing: the meta-acpi project has gathered a lot of SSDT excerpts you may check: https://github.com/westeri/meta-acpi/tree/master/recipes-bsp/acpi-tables/samples (*edison* folder has most of them).

Comment: Thankyou @0andriy! I found the relevant commits from the other driver you pointed me to (sc16is7xx), and now you have saved me the trouble of trying to replicate them myself into the max310x driver. I will rebuild the kernel module with your modifications and retest early next week. Given these changes, I think that my original AML block is already correct or very close.

Comment: Yes, your fist ASL is quite close but you have to drop *clock-names* and *reg* properties and modify driver (after the series applied) to support *clock-frequency* one. Also we accept PRs for **meta-acpi** project (I think your stuff is in category of *minnowboard-max*, since based on BayTrail IIUC).

Comment: My PCB has a layout issue, so I won't be able to finish this until a bit later. My current working diff is posted here (https://pastebin.com/XfL4nvFe) for anyone that has a similar issue. I ended up keeping the "clock-names" as a required parameter since there is a frequency range test in the driver that differs between the oscillator and crystal. I am no longer hung up on the "cannot get clock" issue, but due to the PCB issue the driver is currently failing at device probing (it sees ID 0x00, which is invalid).

Comment: Above mentioned patch series has been applied by Greg for v5.11. From now on it's available in Linux Next repository.

Answer (score 1):

With the driver updates provided by 0andriy (https://lore.kernel.org/linux-serial/20201007084635.594991-1-andy.shevchenko@gmail.com/T/#u), I was able to get the /dev/ttyMAX devices to appear, although I needed to perform further modifications to force oscillator clocking; the driver was still dropping to the "Cannot get clock" error.

I modeled my AML after this example (https://github.com/westeri/meta-acpi/blob/master/recipes-bsp/acpi-tables/samples/edison/sc16is7xx.asl), which resulted in the following:

```asl
DefinitionBlock ("e3900-spi.aml", "SSDT", 5, "INTEL", "SPI", 1)
{
    External (_SB_.PCI0.XHC_.RHUB.HS06.GPIO, DeviceObj)
    External (_SB_.PCI0.SPI1, DeviceObj)

    Scope (\_SB.PCI0.SPI1)
    {
        Device (MAX1) {
            Name (_HID, "PRP0001")
            Name (_DDN, "Maxim MAX14380 Quad UART")
            Name (_CRS, ResourceTemplate () {
                SpiSerialBus (
                    0,                      // Chip select
                    PolarityLow,            // Chip select is active low
                    FourWireMode,           // Full duplex
                    8,                      // Bits per word is 8 (byte)
                    ControllerInitiated,    // slave mode
                    1000000,                // 1 MHz
                    ClockPolarityLow,       // SPI mode 0
                    ClockPhaseFirst,        // SPI mode 0
                    "\\_SB.PCI0.SPI1",      // SPI host controller
                    0,                      // Must be 0
                    ResourceConsumer        // Slave device
                )

                GpioInt (Level, ActiveLow, Exclusive, PullDefault, 0x0000,
                "\\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS06.GPIO", 0x00, ResourceConsumer, , ) { 18 }
            })

            Name (_DSD, Package () {
                ToUUID("daffd814-6eba-4d8c-8a91-bc9bbf4aa301"),
                Package () {
                    Package () {"compatible", "maxim,max14830"},
                    Package () {"clock-frequency", 7372800},
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

However, the driver was still failing in the devm_request_threaded_irq function:

```
[   15.951778] max310x spi-PRP0001:00: MAX14830 ID: 0xb4
[   15.965699] max310x spi-PRP0001:00: Reference clock set to 7372800 Hz
[   15.968883] spi-PRP0001:00: ttyMAX0 at I/O 0x0 (irq = -517, base_baud = 460800) is a MAX14830
[   15.972907] spi-PRP0001:00: ttyMAX1 at I/O 0x20 (irq = -517, base_baud = 460800) is a MAX14830
[   15.985941] spi-PRP0001:00: ttyMAX2 at I/O 0x40 (irq = -517, base_baud = 460800) is a MAX14830
[   15.990046] spi-PRP0001:00: ttyMAX3 at I/O 0x60 (irq = -517, base_baud = 460800) is a MAX14830
[   16.009260] max310x spi-PRP0001:00: Unable to reguest IRQ -517
[   16.021810] max310x: probe of spi-PRP0001:00 failed with error -22
```

Being a novice at C code, I wasn't able to find a way to correct the issue and ended up just commenting it out so that the mounts were not automatically torn down.

At this point, I am able to successfully query them with the setserial utility and access the devices with minicom.

```
[root@hwtest ~]# setserial -g /dev/ttyMAX*
/dev/ttyMAX0, UART: undefined, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: -517, Flags: low_latency
/dev/ttyMAX1, UART: undefined, Port: 0x0020, IRQ: -517, Flags: low_latency
/dev/ttyMAX2, UART: undefined, Port: 0x0040, IRQ: -517, Flags: low_latency
/dev/ttyMAX3, UART: undefined, Port: 0x0060, IRQ: -517, Flags: low_latency
```

I am handing the PCB back to the EE to verify the serial ports are actually working (it does not have easy test points exposed), and I will update this answer if it doesn't.

EDIT: We are able to send data while configured in this manner, but the receive path is not working, likely due to the IRQ issue. I will retest with a 5.11 kernel and report back. The current status is with LTS kernel version 5.4.70, with manual patching of the max310x driver.

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to submit an ASL code to meta-acpi project (https://github.com/westeri/meta-acpi). Btw, check this: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/tty/serial/max310x.c?id=d4d6f03c4fb3a91dadfe147b47edd40e4d7e4d36. Will be part of v5.14-rc1.

Comment: WRT IRQ issue it seems you got `-EPROBE_DEFER` for it. So, by some reason there is no (GPIO) device that should provide an interrupt.